# inserting png introduces inputenc error

Tags: pdftex, pdf, unicode, input-encodings, png

I want to write an article in Chinese, which needs to insert pictures.

It's fine when I insert pictures as `.pdf` but the following problem occurs if `.png` is inserted:

```
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u 8:实 not set up for use with LaTeX.
```

That is a Chinese character.

I compile with `pdflatex` and here is the snippet that is related to the issue:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\usepackage[bookmarks=true, unicode=true, colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\lstset{basicstyle=\large, showstringspaces=false}

\begin{document}
\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{gbsn}

\cleardoublepage
\pdfbookmark[1]{\contentsname}{toc}
\tableofcontents
\newpage

\section{实验设计}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{schema}
\end{figure}

...
```

schema is the picture name.

I have to work around this because the `.pdf` picture will take up the whole page.

Update:

It appears to me that the problem has nothing to do with `inputenc` package.
Although the problem seem to have been solved yesterday after I included the package, it has been weirdly compiling successfully even I exclude it (looking back, it's because I added more characters).

LaTeX complains again after I change the picture floating option, i.e.

```
\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{schema}
\end{figure}
```

Now I guess it's owing to the way Chinese characters mingle with pictures.

**Something I forgot to mention thus far**:

The problem appears on second run and the error is in the `*.toc` file and it goes away after `\tableofcontents` is commented out.

Any thoughts or solutions on this?

**One more thing**:

moving to xelatex has solved the problem to some extent. One more issue is the bookmark is not printed correctly in Chinese character. I've googled a lot but found no satisfactory solution yet. I'm afraid I have to move back if that cannot be handled.

Comment: Have you tried to use `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` as well?

Comment: @guillem    Wow, that works! But how could the format of picture affect the unicode parsing?

Comment: @guillem Make you comment into an answer, because it seems to be the correct answer ;)

Comment: @manuzhang: does it work when no picture is added? it looks like the parser does not know what to do when it reads the first hanzi. I can't explain why `png` does not work in your case, I did not have issues including `jpg` pictures in a beamer presentation with hanzi in it.

Comment: @manuzhang Do you see the problem on the very first run or only after more than one run? I wonder if changing the graphic type is simply co-incidental, and what you are actually seeing is an issue with the section name, which is not available in the `.aux` file in the first pass.

Comment: @JosephWright Now it works even if I exclude that specific package. Very weird.

Comment: @guillem some updates...including the package doesn't work now

Comment: @manuzhang Is using `xetex/xelatex` a viable option? I think Joseph Wright may be right in attributing the problem to the section names. Will it compile when chinese section names are excluded?

Comment: @guillem       I agree...I forgot to mention earlier the error is in the toc file. I have never used xelatex before... Does it compile the same way as paflatex

Comment: @manuzhang In order to use `xelatex` you have to include some packages: `\usepackage{xltxtra}`,`\usepackage{xunicode}``\usepackage{xeCJK}`, and you will probably want to include `\usepackage{fontspec}`. Using `xelatex` you don't need to enclose your text between `\begin{CJK}...` and `\end{CJK}`. The font is selected with `\setCJKmainfont[Scale=1.2]{SimHei}` for instance.

Comment: Removed `png` tag since the problem was not related to png. Added `xetex` tag as it is a viable solution (except for on the bookmarks side)

Comment: @guillem AFAIK the _question_ is tagged only. The solutions can have many other things, but they are not tagged. Therefore `xetex` is wrong here.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek didn't realise that. I will remove the tag then.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that the package `inputenc` is missing. Just add the line

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

to the preamble.

**Update:**

The problem is in fact related to the generation of the table of contents, as reflected in the updated question. It seems that `pdflatex` does not read the `*.toc` files with proper encoding. A solution is to use `xelatex`. The following example compiles on my Linux installation.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setCJKmainfont{SimHei}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{汉语}

汉语.

重要!

\section{English}

English.

\end{document}
```

**Bold Font**

You need to pass the `BoldFont` option to `xeCJK` package, that is, `\usepackage[BoldFont]{xeCJK}`. This is not a real bold font, however, as it is composed from the main font.

You can specify which bold font you want in many ways. For instance,

```
\setCJKmainfont[BoldFont={<appropriate bold font>}]{<appropriate main font>}
```

Comment: @manuzhang Oh! Now that you mention it, I recall having some issues with bookmarks also; don't remember if I solved it, though. Will take a look.

Comment: another thing is that `\textbf` doesn't affect Chinese character

Comment: @manuzhang see updated answer